# How to make flexbox responsive and stack 1 on top of each other

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I'm having trouble making my boxes stack on top of each other when scaled down to mobile size

The ancient way of scaling down using @media and setting width to 100% didnt seem to work with Flexbox

Here is my CSS:

```
.box {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.box .column {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightgray;
  margin-right: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p650fdL4/

Desktop view has 3 equal square boxes next to each other, when in mobile the boxes don't stack

Desktop:
[image: Desktop]

[image: Mobile]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks, i've now included a JSFiddle

Comment: **In the question itself** - right there in bold

Comment: There's no media query in the fiddle - also you might want to look into `flex-wrap:wrap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your chosen media query, set your container box element's flex direction to column:

```
@media screen and (max-width: ___rem) {
    .box { flex-direction: column; }
}
```

The default flex direction is row, which is what your columns are currently displayed in.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-direction/

Answer (score 1):

You were very close.  You need the width: 100% on the columns but flex box items don't wrap to new lines by default.  You need to tell it to wrap on mobile using a media query.

In your mobile media query, make sure to include `flex-wrap: wrap` on the `.box` element

```css
.box { display: -webkit-flex; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex; overflow: hidden; padding-bottom: 1em; text-align: center; flex-wrap: wrap;}
.box .column { flex: 1 1 100%; background: lightgray; margin-right: 1em; padding: 1em; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<div class="box">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="columnBackground">

                    <h3 class="h3Color">We multiply your impact</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="columnBackground">
                    <h3 class="h3Color">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h3>
                    <p>Some info</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="columnBackground">

                    <h3 class="h3Color">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h3>
                    <p>Some info</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this i have already corrected this `use flex: 0 0 100%;` and `max width:100%`  and `flex-wrap: wrap;` for wraping content https://jsfiddle.net/arindam1996/ungarj85/3/ . check this fiddle now